# In selenium web driver how to write wait for drop down to wait and then click on a button

Tags: java, selenium

In my application when i opens a page a dropdown displays and then i need to click on a proceed button. Problem is drop down takes some time to load the values but in my code it click before the drop down loads.I tried with implicit wait and thread.sleep but it some time it work and some time doesn't work.
Code:

```
public class Home {


   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
   {
      File file1 = new File("C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.35.3\\IEDriverServer.exe");     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file1.getAbsolutePath());

     WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
      driver.get("http://10.120.13.100/");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebElement clickBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("btnHomeProceed"));
    clickBtn.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use   `.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("btnHomeProceed")));`

Answer (score 0):

new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("ur xpath"))).click();